# Contract states my notice period is minimum one month at employers discretion, is this enforceable?

Tags: united-kingdom, notice-period

My contract states that my notice period is a minimum of one month, but at my employer's discretion (I don't have the exact wording, but the implication is that any notice will be at least a month but my employer gets to choose how much).

I am about to sign a contract with a new company and hand in my notice, specifying a leaving date which is in excess of one month.

Can my employer force me to change that notice period (I am in the UK)? I am fulfilling the minimum stated, with some extra on top (at least a week).

Comment: You need the exact wording but it sounds like the company has left it open to allow for you to provide a shorter notice at its discretion.  Most companies will utilize your through out your period if you are productive at all since training a new employee and getting them up to that level us usually more expensive than any loss in productivity experienced by employees that are planning on leaving.

Comment: I have worked there for over 2 years. I will find my contract and update with the exact wording when I get home. apologies!

Answer (score 4):

What does your contract say? and how long have you worked there?

In the UK There are two types of notice period: statutory and contractual. Statutory notice is the minimum legal notice that can be given, employer's should give the employee:

- one week's notice if the employee has been employed by the employer
  continuously for one month or more, but for less than two years
- two week's notice if the employee has been employed by the employer
  continuously for two years, and one additional week's notice for each
  further complete year of continuous employment, up to a maximum of 12
  weeks.

Contract would override statutory as long as it no worse that the statutory rights

RE the enforceable part if you do not give your contractual notice (less any outstanding leave) they could deduct that from your last pay check or in extreme cases sue you for breach of contract (if for example you where a highly paid banker joining a competitor)